# In a composition relationship, can a member call a parent method?

Tags: c++, c++14

For example, if the main class is this:

```
class parent{
    public:
        void doSomethingParent(int x);
        member foo;
}
```

and the member class is this

```
class member{
    public:
        void doSomethingMember(int x);
}
```

can `doSomethingMember` call `doSomethingParent`?

One technique would be a `const` reference to the `parent` class in member, but is there any more elegant way?

Comment: Do you mean that `doSomethingMember` should be calling `doSomethingParent`? Please edit your question to indicate that.

Comment: As for your question (if it is as I suspect) then the answer is no. Without a reference to the "parent" object the `member` class doesn't know about it.

Comment: Generally, if you find yourself needing to do something like this then your design is flawed.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Hard to say without context. Could you provide the actual problem you are solving right now?

Comment: In this case, it is a board with a piece stored in it. Is-a will not work.

Answer (score 1):

In my hummble opinion you should change your design and use inheritance. Instead of going with ["has-a"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) design you should change your design to ["is-a"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). Using inheritance things come out more straightforward for the thing you want to accomplish:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual void doSomethingBase(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  void doSomethingDerived(int x) { Base::doSomethingBase(x); }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abb53ca2636f622d)

Comment: Well, only if is-a actually holds, right? If you think, for example, about a linked list that has an inner class LinkedListElement or the like...

Comment: In this case, it is a board with a piece stored in it. Is-a will not work.